# {spacing}, {alignment} & friends

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

At the moment, at least the following tags exist in the spacing/alignment area:

- [spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacing) (137 questions) -- according to its [wiki entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/spacing/info), "[t]his tag marks questions dealing with both horizontal and vertical white space. This might be space between letters or words, or space between lines or paragraphs";
- [line-spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-spacing) (22 questions);
- [setspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setspace) (for the `setspace` package -- 7 questions);
- [vertical-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertical-alignment) (80 questions);
- [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment) (42 questions);
- [alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alignment) (30 questions);
- [vspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vspace) (12 questions);
- [centering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centering) (23 questions);
- [raggedleft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raggedleft) (3 questions);
- [flushright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flushright) (2 questions).

I would leave [spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacing), [line-spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-spacing), [setspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setspace), [vertical-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertical-alignment) and [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment) alone. For the rest, I propose the following:

- Questions tagged with [alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alignment) should be manually assigned to [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment), [vertical-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertical-alignment) or the more general [spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacing) tag;
- Questions tagged with [vspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vspace) should be manually assigned to [vertical-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertical-alignment) or [spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacing);
- [centering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centering), [raggedleft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raggedleft) and [flushright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flushright) should be made synonyms of [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment), and the existing questions should be merged. The (so-far) non existing tags [raggedright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raggedright), [flushleft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flushleft) and [justifying](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/justifying) (a `ragged2e` environment) should also be made synonyms of [horizontal-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment).
- The (so-far) non existing tags [raggedbottom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raggedbottom) and [flushbottom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flushbottom) should be made synonyms of [vertical-alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertical-alignment).

EDIT: As a week has passed and my proposal has gained some upvotes and no downvotes, I ask a moderator to create synonyms and merge existing tags according to points 3 and 4 of my proposal. (Questions tagged with [alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alignment) or [vspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vspace) will be retagged manually, including the modification proposed by Seamus.)

Comment: Points 3 and 4 completed: let me know when I can 'status-complete' this one.

Comment: @Joseph: Status is "complete".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think alignment and spacing are distinct enough concepts that if the spacing tag is surviving, so should the alignment tag. While alignment might well be achieved by using spacing commands, there is a conceptual difference. What I object to is reassigning alignment questions to spacing. That seems to go against the distinction between the concepts.

In response to lockstep's comments, here's what I'd suggest. Try and retag alignment questions with either horizontal-alignment or vertical-alignment and if that fails, use [positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/positioning) rather than [spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spacing). This seems more in the spirit of the difference between spacing and alignment.

Otherwise I endorse the rest of the suggestions.

Comment: I should have been more precise -- I would try to reassign {alignment} questions to either {horizontal-alignment} or {vertical-alignment} (in some instances, both tags may be fitting). If *none* of these tags seems proper, I would consider {spacing} as a last resort.

Comment: Furthermore, the {positionig} tag could be used for "non-standard" cases.

Comment: @lockstep see edit. I think that's a better idea.